# How to escape with backslash only not escaped characters

Tags: python-3.x, regex

How can I escape with backslash only not already escaped characters?
Like I have string

```
@gmail\.com\> \@hotmail.com test1[ test2\[
```

And desired output is:

```
\@gmail\.com\> \@hotmail.com test1\[ test2\[
```

I mean only not escaped @ and [ got escaped.

Tried

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\\\\)(?<!\\\\)([@*])' , r'\\\1','@g*mail\.com\>\@')
'\\@g\\*mail\\.com\\>\\\\@'
```

But get @ and * backslashed.

Comment: Normally you do not need to escape @ or [ in python. I assume you have a reason for doing it?

Comment: Yep. I have some list of characters, that has to be escaped for specific reasons.

Comment: Maybe you need to use .replace() method?

Comment: Case that I have to add backslash, if it is not present already. I mean add \ to @, but not to \@.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to capture all occurrences of the characters you want to escape that isn't prefixed by a slash `\`.

1. Initialize `CHARS_TO_ESCAPE` with all the characters that you want to escape e.g. `@[`. No need to escape them with slash `\` at this point, just put the characters themselves (unless you want to escape the slash character itself which means you might need to make it `\\` as python strings also use it as an escape character).
2. Since we will be using regex, we have to escape the special characters in `CHARS_TO_ESCAPE` that are used in regex patterns such as `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `-`, `^`, etc. We can use [re.escape()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape) for this.
3. Construct a regex pattern that will capture all occurrences of characters in `CHARS_TO_ESCAPE` that isn't prefixed by a slash `\`. Here we used `(?<!\\)(@|\[)`.

   - `(?<!\\)` - Match if the previous character is a non-slash character.
   - `(@|\[)` - Capture group 1 which is any of the characters in `CHARS_TO_ESCAPE`. Notice that `[` is prefixed here with `\`. This is not your escape character but rather is a regex escape character (a bit confusing term as they are both slash `\`).
4. [Substitute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) all found occurrences of the regex pattern (those that aren't prefixed with slash `\`) to have a slash `\` prefix via `\\\1` where group 1 is as described in the previous step.

```
import re

CHARS_TO_ESCAPE = "@["  # Add here all characters that you want to escape
CHARS_TO_ESCAPE_RE = (  # This whole clause is equivalent to: CHARS_TO_ESCAPE_RE = r"(?<!\\)(@|\[)"
    r"(?<!\\)("
    + r"|".join(map(lambda value: re.escape(value), CHARS_TO_ESCAPE))
    + r")"
)
print(f"{CHARS_TO_ESCAPE_RE=}")

text = "@gmail\.com\> \@hotmail.com @yahoomail.com test1[ test2\["
text = re.sub(CHARS_TO_ESCAPE_RE, r"\\\1", text)
print(text)
```

**Output:**

```
CHARS_TO_ESCAPE_RE='(?<!\\\\)(@|\\[)'
\@gmail\.com\> \@hotmail.com \@yahoomail.com test1\[ test2\[
```